# Examples for CNTK Learners

Tags: machine-learning, cntk

I have been going through the Microsft's Python CNTK Tutorials for version 2 Beta 9.0. I haven't found good documentation with examples of recommended values to pass to the different learners available. I have been able to get the following learners working on the *CNTK 103: Part B - Feed Forward Network with MNIST* toturial:

```
    lr_per_minibatch=learning_rate_schedule(0.2, UnitType.minibatch)
    trainer = Trainer(z, ce, pe, sgd(z.parameters, lr=lr_per_minibatch))

    lr_per_minibatch=learning_rate_schedule(0.2, UnitType.minibatch)
    trainer = Trainer(z, ce, pe, adagrad(z.parameters, lr=lr_per_minibatch))

    lr_per_minibatch=learning_rate_schedule(0.05, UnitType.minibatch)
    trainer = Trainer(z, ce, pe, adam_sgd(z.parameters, lr=lr_per_minibatch, momentum=momentum_as_time_constant_schedule(700) ))

    lr_per_minibatch=learning_rate_schedule(0.2, UnitType.minibatch)
    trainer = Trainer(z, ce, pe, nesterov(z.parameters, lr=lr_per_minibatch, momentum=momentum_as_time_constant_schedule(700) ))

    lr_per_minibatch=learning_rate_schedule(0.1, UnitType.minibatch)
    trainer = Trainer(z, ce, pe, rmsprop(z.parameters, lr=lr_per_minibatch, gamma=0.90, inc=0.03, dec=0.03, max=0.1, min=0.1 ))
```

These work, but does anyone have good examples of recommended values of the parameters that each trainer receives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current learners the best parameters depend on the data and the problem you are solving. Therefore it is very hard to provide good recommendations. One typical piece of advice is if a learning rate works then all smaller learning rates will work but you will have to run longer (i.e. do more sweeps over the data).

Comment: Do you have any specific recommendations for the learning rate and momentum, while using the adam_sgd optimizer?

Comment: No but I'm working on a Trainer that doesn't have any tuning parameters.

Comment: That sounds great. I would recommend something else. I have a background of working in CFD Finite element analysis.  Sometimes it was useful to start calculations with one Model or Solver that converged faster in the beginning; and then halfway through the simulation, change to another one that was better or more precise for the later stages of the simulation.

Comment: Though I don't know anyone who's doing exactly this in deep learning, a common practice that is sort of similar is reducing the learning rate. i.e. train  for a few epochs with a constant learning rate, then divide the  learning rate by 10 train for a few epochs, divide the learning rate by 10 and so on. We do support this via learning_rate_schedule. If you look at the plots in the resnet paper you can immediately tell where the learning rate was divided by 10 from the sharp drop in error.